# HTC One M8 Sprint doesn't connect to roaming partners India

Tags: mobile-data, htc-one, roaming, sprint

I am currently in India, and I'm not able to get roaming data with my HTC One M8 Sprint. I have tried several settings and several carriers but to no avail. I have called Sprint but their solutions haven't helped. I have registered for roaming and I verified this on the website. I can connect to carriers to make calls, but I cannot get roaming data.

Is there any way I can fix this without having to call Sprint Customer Support again?

**EDIT**

- Available network operators: Aircel, IND Airtel, Vodafone IN, CellOne
- Network Modes: CDMA Only, LTE/CDMA, GSM/UMTS Only, Automatic
- All roaming guards are disabled.
- Access Point is default Sprint World.
- CDMA roaming mode is set to Automatic
- Domestic Voice,  Domestic Data,  International Voice, International Data, and GSM Data is all enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In India, The Official partner of Sprint in India are MTS(For CDMA/800) and Bharthi Airtel,Aircel for GSM(900,1800). Since you are using CDMA,MTS(Sprint partner) supports basic 1x data. and MTS will only work when you are in Main cities in India. :(

http://www.sprint.com/popups/pop-gprsCarriers.html

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't activate 3G. I connected to IND Airtel and the network mode is GSM/UMTS only. GSM Data is enabled.

Comment: Go to Settings->Mobile data->APN. In the menu select'Reset to default'. It will get the latest GPRS/3G settings from Service provider. IF problem still exist  Then try calling '198' which is Complaint no. for  Airtel where u can get Help